# how to read table values and send to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a table and the values are filled in by the user.  The user can create new rows.

How can I get the values of the table and send it to my controller using jquery or any other method?

Please give me an example.

Comment: what do u mean by table, a database table?

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242914/how-to-send-jquery-list-to-mvc-controller

Comment: @ James Wiseman, yes it is, and I'm glad that finally someone else sees this. user269431 keeps on asking the same question over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class for your cells like class="AnswerCell" and then get the array from jquery like this:

```
val myanswers = $.(".AnswerCell");
```

Then do your post like this:

```
$.post("myActionMethod", {answers: myanswers});
```

and the actionmethod should look like this:

```
public ActionMethod myActionMethod(String[] answers)
{
//do something
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should give a properly names for your inputs, and than you can whether post a form or make asynchronous get using jQuery.getJSON()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {     
    var fieldValue = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();     
});
```

This would use jQuery to pull the 3rd row (it starts at 0) and get the value in the first TD there.  'mytable' is the ID of the table.